How can I install pg_partman using make install?
I am trying to install pg_partman on MacOS as recommended in the repo's readme.md file
However I get the following error after running sudo make install:
Password:
/bin/sh /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/postgresql/extension'
/bin/sh /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/postgresql/extension'
/bin/sh /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/lib/postgresql'
/bin/sh /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/doc/postgresql/extension'
/bin/sh /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../config/install-sh -c -d '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/bin'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//pg_partman.control '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/postgresql/extension/'
install: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/15/share/postgresql/extension//pg_partman.control: Operation not permitted
make: *** [install] Error 71

I have successfully installed it using homebrew but that was causing a different issue. Any idea about how to solve error I got?
Operation not permitted
make: *** [install] Error 71

I am running psql (PostgreSQL) 15.7 (Postgres.app)
